Перезаписывает страницу в Python, Pandas
есть код:
import pandas as pd
import requests  # pip install requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup  # pip install bs4
from counter import integer_part, value

# pip install lxml

count = 2
while count <= integer_part:
    url = (f'https://mircli.ru/{value}/?vid=1&page={count}')
    headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.95 Safari/537.36'}
    data = requests.get(url, headers=headers).text
    block = BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    heads = block.find_all('div', class_='row product-horisont')
    print(len(heads))
    # Подготавливаем списки для хранения данных
    data = {
        'категория': [],
        'наименование': [],
        'цена': [],
        'артикул': [],
        'характеристики': [],
        'фото': []
    }
    for i in heads:
        razdel = i.find_next('p', class_='text-grey').text.strip()
        print(razdel)
        name = i.find_next('p', class_='text-grey').find_next('a').text.strip()
        print(name)
        try:
            price = i.find_next('span', class_='price').text.strip()
            print(price)
        except:
            print('None')
            price = 'None'
        artic = i.find_next('div', class_='block-characteristic').text.strip()
        print(artic)
        pixx = 'https://mircli.ru' + i.find_next('div', class_='block-images-position-bottom').find('img')['src']
        print(pixx)
        try:
            params = i.find_next('ul', class_='menu-dot').find_all('li')
            all_params = []
            for param in params:
                print(' '.join(param.text.strip().split()).replace('?', ''))
                characts = (' '.join(param.text.strip().split()).replace('?', ''))
                all_params.append(characts)
        except:
            print('None')
            characts = 'None'
            all_params.append(characts)
        print('\n')

        # Добавляем данные в соответствующие списки
        data['категория'].append(razdel)
        data['наименование'].append(name)
        data['цена'].append(price)
        data['артикул'].append(artic)
        data['характеристики'].append(all_params)
        data['фото'].append(pixx)
    # Создаем DataFrame
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Сохраняем данные в Excel
    df.to_excel("products.xlsx", index=False)

    print("Данные успешно сохранены в products.xlsx")

    count += 1
    print(count)

ВОПРОС: почему перезаписыватся страница, а не записываются данные совсех страниц? Если кто знает подскажите где ошибка?

Видимо, потому, что вы каждую страницу в цикле сохраняете в один и тот же файл products.xlsx, замещая предыдущие данные последующими. Вам нужно сохранять данные либо в разные файлы, либо на разные листы либо объединять фреймы перед записью

Спасибо. Помогло...
